# Updating a view from parallel threads results

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two threads in my data model layer that run in "parallel" and both compute some values. I have an mvc pattern setup so my data model has two arrays, each responsible for the values generated from each of my threads. How can i tell my view that my arrays have new data without blocking on the main UI?

My threads are running on a timer ever x seconds and generate one integer each. Each of these needs to be added to an array and, when added, the view should get a notification via the observer pattern to update the screen according to the two arrays' updated values. This should happen without ever blocking on the main ui thread. So i cant really do while(true) or set a futureValue for each thread as that would make my ui wait until the threads are done. What can i do?

Comment: You could use either a [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) or maybe a [Producer/Consumer Patterb](http://java.dzone.com/articles/producer-consumer-pattern) depending on your needs.

Comment: Could i potentially have an invokeLater in my thread that updates the array (if i pass it into the thread)?

Comment: @JohnBaum Yes, you could use invokeLater (or invokeAndWait) to have the particular component repaint itself.

Answer (score 1):

You will always:

- Extend the array class that contains the results and overwrite the `add` method
- Put in the `add` at the end the code to inform UI-Thread
- To synchronize the updates, you can use a `ExecutorService` with just one Thread, that you get with `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`. In that you `submit()` the code to inform UI-Thread.
- Your execution should be part of a `WorkerThread` and be handled in `doInBackground`
- In the `done()` method you update the User interface (`done()` is executed on Swing's event dispatch thread)

See here for more information on [Threads and Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: I am using swing. Also why synchronize? I am only ever updating inside the threads and each thread has their own array

Comment: Oh, each thread has its own array. I edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a pretty complex approach. Here is mine:

- Create a [blocking queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)
- Get rid of the arrays and have each thread put their results in the queue
- Start a worker thread that waits for items in the queue
- Use [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) in the worker thread to update the UI.